# Alternative answer notification system (used when composing an answer) doesn't trigger MathJax rendering

Tags: bug, mathjax, answers, live-refresh

When composing an answer, a notification for new answers appears in a blue bar at the top of the screen, rather than the usual one directly below the question.

This notification does not trigger MathJax rendering upon loading the new answers (namely, no typesetting is done at all).

Can we get this resolved please?

---

**Edit:** It has recurred; I have rephrased the question to reflect the information since obtained. Here are also two screenshots:

## Before loading:

[image]

## After loading:

[image]

Comment: Could you include a screenshot? For me, the bar appears under the question, and when the answer loads, MathJax processes it.

Comment: @user79365 It seems the original system is back cq. still in place. I'll update if it recurs.

Comment: @ˈjuː.zɚ79365 It has recurred, see the edit.

Comment: I think this is a well-documented bug, actually.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It appears that all issues on MSO are closed [meta-tag:status-completed] and pertain to the standard "1 new answer to this question" version instead of the blue bar.

Comment: I don't think there are many $\TeX$ related bugs on MSO, those would have a greater chance appearing on this site.